# symfony2 and dropzone.js save issues

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I've one application to upload files.
I'm using the script Dropzone.js and i followed one answer here to make this working with symfony.

the controller:

```
    public function indexAction() {
        return $this->render('testDropzoneBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function uploadAction() {
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $files = $request->files;

        foreach ($files as $uploadedFile) {
            $name = uniqid();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $f = new File();
            $f->setName(($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());
            $f->setFile($uploadedFile);
            $f->preUpload();
            $f->upload();
            $em->persist($f);
            $em->flush();
        }
        return new Response($name);
    }
```

and the view:

```
<form action="{{ path('upload') }}" method="post" class="dropzone">
<div class="fallback" id="mydropzone">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
</div>
```

but now I want to set a name for each file that I drag on the page.
I want to show a dialog asking the name.
like this:
dropzone.js line 538

```
var myName = prompt('Enter the name for file '+file.name);
file.name = myName;
```

But how can I send the name from the script to controller?

Comment: `file.name = myName;` here file is an instance of what? Dropzone?

Comment: yes. but the proble is that the file.name will never assume myName. where should I ask the name and replace?

Comment: So basically you want to let your user to drag the file to the browser, and then in a prompt dialog she enters the file name she desires, and after hitting ok the file gets uploaded and saved with the name the user has chosen.

Comment: exactly. I have almost everything ready, i can upload files, i can save the file from the script. But I cant change the name of file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the name to the php script. You have 2 [options](http://www.dropzonejs.com):

1. Dropzone will submit any hidden fields you have in your dropzone form
2. Append the filename to the form data upon upload
3. You can also use the `params` option

If you go with the first one, before uploading, prompt the user for the filename, once you get the filename append a hidden input to the form on the fly, something like this (haven't tested):

```
var name = prompt('Name the file');

$('#myDropzoneForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="clientFilename" value="' + name + '"');
```

Option 2:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#myId', { url: "/file/post" });

myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
    var name = prompt('Name the file');
    formData.append('clientFilename', name);
});
```

Comment: when I try this: var myDropzone = new Dropzone('dropzone', {url: "/file/post"}); i got the error "Invalid dropzone element. "

Comment: you are missing a dot there: .dropzone

Comment: when I use this: var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#mydropzone', {url: "/file/post"}); nothing happens, the file is uploaded as before but dont ask me the name. check my edit

Comment: what version of dropzone are you using?

Comment: and maybe can work with this : Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            $(function() {
                var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", {url: "/test/web/app_dev.php/dropzone/upload"});
                myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                    var name = prompt('Name the file');
                    formData.append('clientFilename', name);
                });

            });

Comment: but now I got formData is not defined

Comment: make sure you pass xhr and formData variables to your addedfile listener.